# Dynamically modify head tag from web page in a

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

I have a domain registrar that when doing a domain forward it wraps your site in frameset
so What i want to do it add a line right below there  tag to define a FAVICON.ICO
like thi s

change 
%3C%2FHEAD%3E 
    to
%3Clink+rel%3D%27shortcut+icon%27+href%3D%27%2FPictureLibrary%2Ffavicon.ico%27+%2F%3E
%3C%2FHEAD%3E

how could I do this using jquery or dynamic javascript/html?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>smdug.tk</title>
    <meta name="description" content="smdug.tk">
    <meta name="keywords" content="bodyareaframe,accessible,content">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <frameset rows="*">
    <frame frameborder=0 src="http://portal.merrittnet.org/smdug" name="dot_tk_frame_content" scrolling="auto" noresize>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

javaScript code:

```
<script>
        icon_link = document.createElement('link'); //create an <link> tag
 // add attributes to the <link> tag 
        icon_link.rel = 'shortcut icon';                    
        icon_link.href = 'PictureLibrary-favicon.ico';  
        icon_link.type = 'image/x-icon';
// attach created <link> tag along with it's attributes to DOM 
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(icon_link);
</script>
```