# How to dynamically load the URLs in an HTML head tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to load my CSS and JS files based on a localStorage variable.

It looks just like this:

```js
let jx = localStorage.getItem('jurisdiction');

document.write(`

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../_externals/stylesheets/assist/${jx}.css">
    
 `);
```

However this doesn't seem to work and I can't find a solution how to dynamically change a URL in the head tag.

I'd appreciate any help as to how to go about this. Thank you!

Comment: Try the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898550/dynamically-modify-head-tag-from-web-page-in-a

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What happens?  Do you see any attempt to load the CSS?  If so where is the request going?  Also add some some debugging like `console.log(jx)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that href in your  tag should look like this:
href=`../_externals/stylesheets/assist/${jx}.css`

Notice that I have used template literals(``) to wrap the link in 'href' attribute.
In order to use the ${jx} inside your link, you need to wrap the whole link inside the template literals(e.g. `text${jsVariables}`). I think this should work.